# How to visualize such regions in complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I was wondering whether the open sets in complex plane which are bounded by rectifiable simple closed curves are in fact simply connected? In particular, what is the significance of considering the regions bounded by rectifiable curves while performing surface integral on complex plane. Intuitively, it feels like that such regions should be connected and without any holes.

For context, consider the following theorem:
[image]

Comment: Isn't e.g. a set $D(0, 1) \cup D(3, 1)$ open an bounded by a rectifiable curve (say a circle centered at $0$ with radius $5$)? By $D(z, r)$ I mean an open disk centered at $z$ with radius $r$.

Comment: @paler123 That's the confusion I have. Is the curve supposed to only bound the region or any random set containing the region? Will an annulus qualify as an open region bounded by a rectifiable curve?

Comment: Yes, an annulus will count.... these regions need not be simply connected.  This is more of a technical restriction to rule out "wild" boundaries like the Koch curve.

Comment: @mjqxxxx But isn't annulus bounded by two rectifiable curves? Is the theorem applicable to an annulus?

Comment: The formulas (6) and (7) give the value $f(z)$ in terms of a path integral around $\gamma$ and a double integral over the whole region $D$. For the equation still to be valid over another $D' \subset D$, the integral over $D'$ must equal the integral over $D$. This won't in general be the case (unless $f$ is identically zero!). So, no, an arbitrary subset of the simply connected region inside $\gamma$ won't do.(Sorry, mjqxxxx.)